# How do I use a font that is in a different assembly in VS2019?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, .net-assembly

As the title already says, I want to use a font (Font Awesome 5, otf-format), which is in a class library. So I have a WPF project (UI.Desktop) and a class library (UI.Assets). "UI.Desktop" references "UI.Assets". In the UI.Assets project there is (currently) only one folder "Fonts", in which the font is located (Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf). Now I try to use this font in my MainWindow (the MainWindow.xaml in the "UI.Desktop" project is located in a subfolder "Views").

I would like the font to be in the assembly, so I defined it with the build action "Resource" and "Do not copy". I've already made countless attempts, searched various forums (also here on SO), but found nothing that helped me. However: The icon is displayed in the designer, so the path seems to be correct. Only when I compile the program and run it, you see only the empty rectangle.

This will, for example, display the icon in the Designer, but not during runtime.

```
<Button Padding="10 0"
        Content="&#xf2b9;"
        Foreground="White"
        FontFamily="/UI.Assets;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"
        />
```

All the other things I've tried:

```
FontFamily="/UI.Assets;component/Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"
FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/UI.Assets;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"
FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/UI.Assets;component/Fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Regular-400.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"
```

I have also tried different build actions and with "always copy", unfortunately without success.

As far as I know, it probably has something to do with the Visual Studio 2019 version. I know it worked with the 2017 version (with "/UI.Assets;component/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular"). But in the 2019 version this doesn't work anymore, for reasons unknown to me. Now I didn't find any information about any changes in the URI specification between the 2017 and 2019 version.

UPDATE 29.08.19:
After I didn't manage it, I wanted to load the icons into the program as images (for now, instead of using FontAwesome as font). The problem: The image is shown in the designer, but not during the runtime of the program. Sort of, as if the image would simply not be found at runtime. So there must be something wrong with the URI, but no idea what. The image is located in UI.Assets and is defined as "Content" and "Copy if Newer".

```
<Image Source="/UI.Assets;component/Images/Close.png"
       Width="10"
       />
```

Comment: There is a memory leak waiting to catch you out when you get this working. Any relative path ( a path that doesn't start with something like C:\\ ) will mean memory leaks. Instead or embedding, distribute the ttf as a separate file and use the absolute path.  https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/746

Comment: I've implemented it now, but the font is not displayed in the designer or at runtime. You only see the empty rectangle. But thanks for the info, it's definitely interesting.